# BeautifulSoup module isn't detecting any tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm a newbie to python and trying to do a project where I open all review links on an Amazon product page. Why isn't the `soup.select()` method working in finding the proper **html tags** for the python links?

```
import webbrowser, requests, sys, bs4, logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(asctime)s - % (levelname)s - %(message)s')
print("Searching...") # Text to display while searching amazon

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) 
        AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 
        Safari/537.36'}
url = input("Enter the url: ")
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
res.raise_for_status()

# Retrieve reviews found
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features='html.parser')

# Open a tab for each review found
linkElems = soup.select('div.a-row a.a-size-base.a-link-normal.review- 
    title.a-color-base.a-text-bold')
numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))
logging.debug(linkElems)
for i in range(numOpen):
    logging.debug("Link is: " + str(linkElems[i].get('href')))
    webbrowser.open('https://amazon.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

I expected this code to produce and open a list of product review links, however when I run it the list for found tags turns up empty.

Answer (score 0):

**update 1:**
as op edited his post and fixed the whitespaces in his code format, i'm updating my answer.

when the program ask for the link, write(or paste) your link and *add one whitespace before pressing enter*.

the extra whitespace in the end of your input will prevent the IDE from opening the link in your browser window instead of ended the input with the return key, so it will continue as expected to execute next code after input function.

doing that, your code actually work fine as i demonstrate in my first answer.

**my previous answer:**
i noticed that you have incorrect whitespace here 'a- color-base'

replace this line :

```
linkElems = soup.select('div.a-row a.a-size-base.a-link-normal.review-title.a- color-base.a-text-bold')
```

with

```
linkElems = soup.select('div.a-row a.a-size-base.a-link-normal.review-title.a-color-base.a-text-bold')
```

---

**extra:**
also currently your code work only with amazon.com , to make your code work with other amazons sites like amazon.in amazon.co.uk you need to modify this line:

```
webbrowser.open('https://amazon.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

to something like:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url_components = urlparse(url)
webbrowser.open('https://' + url_components.netloc + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

now it will work correctly with other amazon sites like amazon.in, not only amazon.com, try it.

**testdrive:**

```
Enter the url: https://www.amazon.in/Intex-PB-16K-Poly-16000mAH-Lithium/dp/B07843GH8X/ref=cm_cr_srp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8 
 2019-02-15 22:51:28,940 - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.amazon.in:443
 2019-02-15 22:51:30,125 - DEBUG - https://www.amazon.in:443 "GET /Intex-PB-16K-Poly-16000mAH-Lithium/dp/B07843GH8X/ref=cm_cr_srp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8%20 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
 2019-02-15 22:51:32,019 - DEBUG - [<a class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" data-hook="review-title" href="/gp/customer-reviews/R123ICSCDM2MF3/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&amp;ASIN=B07843GH8X">Nice product.</a>, <a class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" data-hook="review-title" href="/gp/customer-reviews/R3OTWE19SMPPVQ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&amp;ASIN=B07843GH8X">Not a good product. It takes a day to charge the ...</a>, <a class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" data-hook="review-title" href="/gp/customer-reviews/R1Z51ERFCD7D6P/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&amp;ASIN=B07843GH8X">not portable easily..</a>, <a class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" data-hook="review-title" href="/gp/customer-reviews/R24GYC4HRBGTM1/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&amp;ASIN=B07843GH8X">Five Stars</a>, <a class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" data-hook="review-title" href="/gp/customer-reviews/R2P5ILE8KQF8PJ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&amp;ASIN=B07843GH8X">Fine not superb</a>, <a class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" data-hook="review-title" href="/gp/customer-reviews/R3C9ZYFRT9NWAK/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&amp;ASIN=B07843GH8X">Quality &amp; Performance</a>, <a class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" data-hook="review-title" href="/gp/customer-reviews/R16F4OE3LWHHQI/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&amp;ASIN=B07843GH8X">Worst experience. Don’t buy</a>, <a class="a-size-base a-link-normal review-title a-color-base a-text-bold" data-hook="review-title" href="/gp/customer-reviews/R26ROATK8PU6TL/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&amp;ASIN=B07843GH8X">Very bad product</a>]
 2019-02-15 22:51:32,019 - DEBUG - Link is: /gp/customer-reviews/R123ICSCDM2MF3/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B07843GH8X
 2019-02-15 22:51:32,295 - DEBUG - Link is: /gp/customer-reviews/R3OTWE19SMPPVQ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B07843GH8X
 2019-02-15 22:51:32,628 - DEBUG - Link is: /gp/customer-reviews/R1Z51ERFCD7D6P/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B07843GH8X
 2019-02-15 22:51:32,933 - DEBUG - Link is: /gp/customer-reviews/R24GYC4HRBGTM1/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B07843GH8X
 2019-02-15 22:51:33,302 - DEBUG - Link is: /gp/customer-reviews/R2P5ILE8KQF8PJ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B07843GH8X
```

**in case your debug function throw error:** 
i'm not sure if this space in your actual code or it shows here by bad post format but anyway you should remove the whitespace from format arg '% (levelname)s' for debug to work as expected:

replace this:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(asctime)s - %  (levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

with

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Yeah, sorry the white space is just bad post format

Comment: okay, i see you now fixed the white space in the post . did you use pycharm ?  when the program ask for the link, write the link and add whitespace before pressing enter. this will prevent the IDE from opening the link in new window instead of ended the input with the return key and continue to execute next code after input function.

Answer (score 0):

The white space issue has been mentioned. You are however using a long, and therefore slower, selector which may also be more brittle. You can use the more performant:

```
linkElems = soup.select("a.review-title")
```

Or even faster

```
linkElems = soup.select(".review-title")
```

class selectors are the second fastest selector method after id.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried all of that to no success

Comment: Can you give me a failing url please.